# Traversing binary trees through and through

Tags: java, unit-testing, tree

Given a binary tree, it's quite common to perform some operation on all nodes while traversing pre-order, in-order, post-order or level-order, depending on the task at hand. For example you might want to extract sorted elements from a binary search tree, for which in-order traversal is handy. Or do a breadth first search to find the shortest path to an element from the root, for which level-order traversal is handy.

Given a `TreeNode` defined as:

```
public class TreeNode<T> {
    public final T value;
    public TreeNode<T> left;
    public TreeNode<T> right;

    public TreeNode(T x) {
        value = x;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
}
```

The utility class to generate the various iterators:

```
package com.janosgyerik.examples.tree.binarytree;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Iterators {

    private Iterators() {
        // utility class, forbidden constructor
    }

    public static <T> Iterator<T> preOrderIterator(TreeNode<T> root) {
        return new PreOrderIterator<>(root);
    }

    public static <T> Iterator<T> inOrderIterator(TreeNode<T> root) {
        return new InOrderIterator<>(root);
    }

    public static <T> Iterator<T> postOrderIterator(TreeNode<T> root) {
        return new PostOrderIterator<>(root);
    }

    public static <T> Iterator<T> levelOrderIterator(TreeNode<T> root) {
        return new LevelOrderIterator<>(root);
    }

    private static class PreOrderIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
        private final Stack<TreeNode<T>> stack = new Stack<>();

        private PreOrderIterator(TreeNode<T> root) {
            if (root != null) {
                stack.push(root);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return !stack.isEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            TreeNode<T> node = stack.pop();
            if (node.right != null) {
                stack.push(node.right);
            }
            if (node.left != null) {
                stack.push(node.left);
            }
            return node.value;
        }
    }

    private static class InOrderIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
        private Stack<TreeNode<T>> stack = new Stack<>();

        private InOrderIterator(TreeNode<T> root) {
            moveToLeftMost(root);
        }

        private void moveToLeftMost(TreeNode<T> node) {
            while (node != null) {
                stack.push(node);
                node = node.left;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return !stack.isEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            TreeNode<T> current = stack.pop();
            moveToLeftMost(current.right);
            return current.value;
        }
    }

    private static class PostOrderIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
        private Stack<TreeNode<T>> stack = new Stack<>();

        private PostOrderIterator(TreeNode<T> root) {
            moveToNextLeaf(root);
        }

        private void moveToNextLeaf(TreeNode<T> node) {
            while (node != null) {
                stack.push(node);
                node = node.left != null ? node.left : node.right;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return !stack.isEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            TreeNode<T> current = stack.pop();
            if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                TreeNode<T> parent = stack.peek();
                if (parent.right != current) {
                    moveToNextLeaf(parent.right);
                }
            }
            return current.value;
        }
    }

    private static class LevelOrderIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
        private final Queue<TreeNode<T>> queue = new LinkedList<>();

        private LevelOrderIterator(TreeNode<T> root) {
            queue.add(root);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return !queue.isEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            TreeNode<T> current = queue.poll();

            if (current.left != null) {
                queue.add(current.left);
            }
            if (current.right != null) {
                queue.add(current.right);
            }

            return current.value;
        }
    }
}
```

Unit tests:

```
package com.janosgyerik.examples.tree.binarytree;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class IteratorsTest {

    // example tree from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal
    /*
            F
        B       G
      A   D       I
         C E     H
          */
    private final TreeNode<Character> root;

    public IteratorsTest() {
        root = new TreeNode<>('F');
        root.left = new TreeNode<>('B');
        root.left.left = new TreeNode<>('A');
        root.left.right = new TreeNode<>('D');
        root.left.right.left = new TreeNode<>('C');
        root.left.right.right = new TreeNode<>('E');
        root.right = new TreeNode<>('G');
        root.right.right = new TreeNode<>('I');
        root.right.right.left = new TreeNode<>('H');
    }

    static <T> List<T> iterateToList(Iterator<T> iterator) {
        List<T> list = new LinkedList<>();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            list.add(iterator.next());
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Test
    public void testPreOrderIterator() {
        Iterator<Character> iterator = Iterators.preOrderIterator(root);
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList('F', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'I', 'H'), iterateToList(iterator));
    }

    @Test
    public void testInOrderIterator() {
        Iterator<Character> iterator = Iterators.inOrderIterator(root);
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'), iterateToList(iterator));
    }

    @Test
    public void testPostOrderIterator() {
        Iterator<Character> iterator = Iterators.postOrderIterator(root);
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList('A', 'C', 'E', 'D', 'B', 'H', 'I', 'G', 'F'), iterateToList(iterator));
    }

    @Test
    public void testLevelOrderIterator() {
        Iterator<Character> iterator = Iterators.levelOrderIterator(root);
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList('F', 'B', 'G', 'A', 'D', 'I', 'C', 'E', 'H'), iterateToList(iterator));
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a review of all aspects of all the above code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TreeNode

*I'm not sure, if you find this applicable, but using it the code may get more generally usable.*

> Given a TreeNode defined as:

This is the first problem. There are quite a few tree nodes out there, which don't extend `TreeNode`, most notably `File`, `XMLNode`, `XmlNode` (really, both exist), and `javax.swing.tree.TreeNode`. An interface wouldn't help here unless we expect Oracle to retrofit Java. *I'm aware that all my examples are wrong as none of them is a binary tree.*

You can try to wrap e.g. `File` in a subclass of your `TreeNode`, but then you need a way to get the latter given the former and `new MyFileTreeNode(file)` doesn't help as you need exactly the same instance as before.

The easy way is to define a class like

```
public abstract class TreeNodeAdapter<T> {
    public TreeNode<T> left(T value);
    public TreeNode<T> right(T value);
}
```

and work with the values directly.

### Iterators

```
import java.util.Stack;
```

Don't use this synchronized crap. Unfortunately, `ArrayList` lacks `pop` and `peek`, which makes using it more verbose, but otherwise it's fine (and efficient). There's also `ArrayDeque`, which has all needed operations, albeit named differently.

```
public static <T> Iterator<T> levelOrderIterator(TreeNode<T> root) {
```

This could use some short documentation about what it does (the others are obvious).

```
public static <T> Iterator<T> preOrderIterator(TreeNode<T> root) {
    return new PreOrderIterator<>(root);
}
```

It'd nicer to have a `PreOrderIterable` and call

```
for (T t : root.preorderIterable()) {....}
```

but it'd mean to write quite some boilerplate.

```
    private PreOrderIterator(TreeNode<T> root) {
        if (root != null) {
            stack.push(root);
        }
    }
```

So you're silently converting `null` into an empty iterator. Is this wise? I strongly prefer being [fail-fast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast), but I guess, that `null` is actually the empty tree and then everything's fine...

Maybe except for identifying nodes with trees as rolfl wrote. That feels a bit hacky, but looking at my `File` example above, there's no corresponding tree class and nobody seems to miss it.

```
    public T next() {
        TreeNode<T> node = stack.pop();
        ...
    }
```

You throw an `EmptyStackException`, but it should be a `NoSuchElementException`. This requires an explicit `hasNext()` check at the beginning.

Or you can extend Guava's [AbstractIterator](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/AbstractIterator.java). This would also help you with missing `remove()` - you code can't compile or am I blind??? I see, default method, so Java 8 only. Just add a big warning sign "not for android and not for maaartinus).

### IteratorsTest

From the example tree it's pretty hard to see if your test cases are correct. Without looking at the picture, I have no idea if

```
'A', 'C', 'E', 'D', 'B', 'H', 'I', 'G', 'F'
```

is the right thing. And even with the picture it takes a while. I'd go for a tree like

```
        T
    L       R
LL    LR       RR
   LRL  LRR  RRL
```

I guess, you could use more tests, and then it gets important. I'd also join the lists as

```
"A C E D B H I G F"
```

is not such a pain to type.

Some of the iterators are rather complicated and I can't see if `PostOrderIterator` is right. If I really wanted to be sure, I'd add some pseudo-randomly generated trees and compare the iterator-produced list with what a recursive implementation does (which is e.g. for the first three iterators very trivial).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 'feeling' the concept here. There's a disconnect between what you have, and what you're doing. You are asking for an iterator, but passing in a node.... that makes no sense. You should be passing in a `Tree`.

The `TreeNode` should not be public... it should be attached to a new `Tree` class in a more restricted way. Perhaps a `Tree` interface and then a number of implementations like `BalancedTree`, etc.

So, it's a design issue...

Then, about the Iterators, you're taking advantage of Java8 Default methods on the Iterator (the default `remove()` implementation), but then really, you should be streaming things, not iterating them. A Spliterator is what you should be implementing.

In a sense, I see your code as being a good solution to a 'local' problem, but the way you describe the code is that it should be some form of API, and, as a library, it's problematic.

Comment: I was thinking about the first paragraph... and there is `File` which is a tree node, but there's no corresponding tree. Each file has a subtree below it and it's fine. +++ So maybe a `Tree` makes only sense when you really need to abstract away the nodes like in a `TreeMap`.